# Order partitioned steps in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have implemented Spring batch [partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) and I was returning a `Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();` from partition() method of `Partitioner`.

My requirement is to start slave steps in specific order( Insertion Order to `result` map)  and that is not happening with above `Map`.

I tried to use `Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();` and that is also not useful - any thread from map gets started randomly.

I am using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` as executor in master step configuration and `concurrencyLimit` parallel threads get started. If I set `concurrencyLimit=1`, then I want first thread inserted to `result` map to get started and so on.

How can I implement this ordering?

Comment: Partitioning isn't intended to guarantee the order of worker execution.  Since they should be processed in parallel, I'm not sure I understand why you would need to.  If you can provide why you need to run them in a particular order, we may be able to help with an alternative.

Comment: Basically we have 235 clients with varying counts of data to be processed. We need ordering because we want to process highest count clients first and so on. All clients will be processed eventually but we wish to start highest count N-Threads first to have better throughput and don't want to have a situation where a few thousand client is waiting for a few million client to finish up.Each slave step represents a client.

Comment: @MichaelMinella: I have used `LinkedHashMap` in my partitioner and wrote a splitter as suggested in Karthik Prasad's answer and that did the job. Is that a correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Looking at code, along with above step you might need to override StepExecutionSplitter#split, I believe you can extend SimpleStepExecutionSplitter class and implement Split method, in split method you need to change set used for collecting StepExecution from HashSet to LinkedHashSet, if you want to consider restart as well then you might need to consider changing in getContexts method as well.

Below is the snippet to add splitter.

```
stepBuilders.get("partitionStep")
                .partitioner(slaveStep)
                .partitioner("myParitionerStep", partitioner)
                .taskExecutor(new SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor())
                .splitter(new SimpleStepExecutionSplitter(jobRepository, allowStartIfComplete, stepName, partitioner))
                .build()
```

Comment: or do I need to provide a partition handler similar to `org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` by overriding `doHandle()` method and provide to step by `.partitionHandler(partitionHandler)`? Partition handler is the one launching threads and calling splitter.

Comment: If you see the code doHandle is called by handle, in handle method using splitter you get all stepExecution, you need these stepExecutions in order. Hence Splitter needs to be modified.