# Spring Batch : MultiResourcePartitioner How to set order resources by name files

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have Job Spring Batch which read and write multiple files for that i'm use MultiResourcePartitioner for reading multiple files.

When i set the list of files to resources (partitionner.setResources(listFiles)) the pMultiResourcePartitioner randomly processes files does not respect the order of files in listFiles

this my code :

```
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public MultiResourcePartitioner paritioner() throws IOException {
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        Resource[] resources = new Resource[listFiles.size()];
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

        HashMap<Integer, String> collect = listFiles
            .stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(HashMap<Integer, String>::new, (map, streamValue) -> map.put(map.size(), streamValue), (mapFirst, mapSecond) -> {
            });
        collect.forEach((index, value) -> resources[index] = resolver.getResource("file:" + value));

        partitioner.partition(1);
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        return partitioner;
    }
```

How to avoid random process file in MultiResourcePartitioner

Comment: There is an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479240/order-partitioned-steps-in-spring-batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you decide to use a partitioned step, you should be assuming that partitions will be processed in parallel by different workers (which could be local threads or remote worker JVMs). Going parallel is not compatible with ordering. The order in which partitions are processed in undefined.

In your case, the `MultiResourcePartitioner` will create a partition per file, and each file will be processed by a distinct worker. The order in which you pass resources to the partitioner does not (and should not) matter.